# ASP.net MVC 3 with web service

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services

I am the new one with the using of web service with ASP.net MVC 3.0. Now I have another member in my team, they develop web service and then they passed the URL to me `http://localhost:55274/iServices/Generics/Setting.svc/GetSetting/` , then I received the JSON data

```
{"ID":1,"MailAccount":"blahbla.com","MailPassword":"password","SMTP":"smtp.test.com","SMTPPort":500,"SSL":false}
```

Now I am trying to get that JSON to use in the class of my ASP.net MVC 3 to provide the mail system setting. I created two class :

```
public class iceEmailObject
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public String SMTP { set; get; }
    public int SMTPPort { set; get; }
    public String MailAccount { set; get; }
    public String MailPassword { set; get; }
    public bool SSL { set; get; }
}
```

The second class is to handle send mail :

```
public class EASEmail : ItemEntityDataContext
{
public bool SendMail(string ReplyTo, string SendTo, string Title, string Body, string From, string AttachmentPath, bool isHtml = false)
{
    try
    {
        SmtpMail oMail = new SmtpMail("blah blah blah");
        SmtpClient oSmtp = new EASendMail.SmtpClient();

        String fff = From;
        if (From == "") fff = ReplyTo;

        MailAddress ma = new EASendMail.MailAddress(fff, "");

        if (From == "")
        {
            oMail.ReplyTo = ReplyTo;
            oMail.Headers.Add("Reply-To", ReplyTo);
        }
        oMail.From = ma;

        oMail.To = SendTo;
        oMail.Subject = Title;
        oMail.Priority = MailPriority.High;

        if (!isHtml)
            oMail.TextBody = Body;
        else
            oMail.HtmlBody = Body;

            iceEmailObject mail = new iceEmailObject();
            mail.ID = blahblah;      //data from web service here
            mail.MailAccount = ""; //data from web service here
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

I want to get the JSON to initial the object of the first class such as `mail.ID = ...`.

Could any one tell me how could I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

iceEmailObject mail = js.Deserialize<iceEmailObject>(json);
```

where json is your JSON string, and mail is the resulting object

Comment: Thanks Matt Tew, but how could I get the JSON string, as you see in the beginning of my question. My work mate just gave me the URL and then when I browse it, I can see the JSON string, but I don't know how to get that string.

Comment: Ah, right.  In that case, I would consider just adding the url as a web reference to your project, and then you can just call the method in code.  Otherwise, use the HttpWebRequest object

Comment: @socheata if you right click your project and add a web/service reference then enter the URL http://localhost:55274/iServices/Generics/Setting.svc visual studio will generate the code for you

Comment: Thanks Daveo, I tried it, but it has an error `SystemSetting/ was not recognized as a known document type.` while I entered the URL.